# Is it possible to create an object and call a method in one statement?

Tags: c++, constructor

So to not get accused of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) again here is the full picture:

I'm implementing [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) and the current feature I want is `INFO()`. It works like this:

```
int var1 = 1;
{
    int var2 = 666;
    INFO(var1 << "some string" << var2); // INFO is a macro
    // random code...
    CHECK(var1 == 42); // only if this fails should we see the INFO text
}
CHECK(var1 == 42); // INFO is scoped and should not be relevant here
```

This is easy. I want however 2 things in addition to this simple behavior:

- I want lazy string construction - only if the assert fails
- I dont want ANY allocations (atleast for small number of variables passed to `INFO()`) - I want to use the stack (employing something like the small buffer optimization). Note that I keep on the stack pointers to the objects for stringification - not the actual string results. Also in the case of C++11 rvalue references I delete the `operator<<` overload for `&&` so no rvalues can bind to it - since I'm saving pointers.

I **have** done both of these things but I noticed that my `INFO()` macro is not a single statement. That is a deal breaker - and I cannot wrap the whole thing inside of a `do { ... } while(false)` to make it a single statement because `INFO()` is scoped - thats the whole point for it...

Here is the `INFO()` macro:

```
#define INFO_IMPL(name, x) InfoBuilder name; name << x
#define INFO(x) INFO_IMPL(anon_name, x)
```

My rival [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) implements the `INFO()` macro as a single statement like [this](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/79ce6930a2def57478a3d79f5f0573273626cb37/single_include/catch.hpp#L2259) but the thing is that the object onto which `operator<<` is called is a temporary which gets assigned to the real object that will be on the stack.

```
ScopedMessage anon_name = MessageBuilder() << x; // simplification
```

This is not an option for me since I need the stack space for the `operator<<` calls.

If I dont use the stack then I will only have lazy stringifications - but there will be allocations.

Is there a way to both construct an object and call a method on it in a single statement? Something like this:

```
InfoBuilder info() << x
```

And also I need this in C++98.

I tried the following nonsense (to pass a reference to the scoped object to the one being assigned to it) - which cannot work in C++...

```
struct Y;

struct X {
    X(Y&){}
};

struct Y {
    Y(X&, int){}
};

int main() {
    X x(Y(x, 6));
}
```

Comment: What about simply `#define INFO(x) InfoBuilder() << x` ?  It creates a temp unnamed object, streams to it, and then destroys it when it goes out of scope on the following `;`. You don't need to give an object/variable a name unless you need to refer to it in multiple statements

Comment: will it be alive until the assert below it? won't it die instantly? If this is possible I would be SO HAPPY

Comment: If you give it a name, then yes, it will stay alive as long as that name stays in scope.  If it does not have a name, then no, it will die immediately. You did not say the object created by `INFO()` had to survive and be available to `CHECK()`. But why do you care if the `INFO()` macro is implemented as a single statement? It doesn't need to be, you can have multiple statements in it: `#define INFO(x) InfoBuilder anon_name; anon_name << x` You cannot invoke `operator<<` in the same statement that constructs the object, if that object needs a name.

Comment: Well in that case I do need a name - the variables need to be "captured" for the entire scope - and only if an assert fails to stringify/print them

Comment: What Catch is doing (`ScopedMessage anon_name = MessageBuilder() << x`) is about as good as you can get. Why exactly don't you want to use it? What does "*This is not an option for me since I need the stack space for the `operator<<` calls*" actually mean? What do you think it is preventing you from doing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau it means that I cache pointers to the objects for stringification inside of ```InfoBuilder``` (or ```MessageBuilder``` in the case of Catch) inside of a small embedded buffer on the stack - and only if more than 5 things are streamed to ```INFO``` does it start using the heap. I want 0 allocations in the common case - where few things are logged and no asserts fail. And in the case of Catch ```MessageBuilder``` is a temporary - so if I save anything inside of it it would be basically worthless

Comment: Why does that prevent you from implementing what Catch does? Just give `InfoBuilder` a copy/move constructor, or a `swap()` method, that `INFO()` can use to move the relevant pointers from one instance to another without reallocating anything. `#define INFO(x) InfoBuilder anon_name(InfoBuilder() << x)` or `#define INFO(x) InfoBuilder anon_name; (InfoBuilder() << x).swap(anon_name)` or something like that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I think about it... I could do something like that. Will try it in the morning - thanks!

Comment: What does "I need the stack space for the operator<< calls." mean?

Comment: @immibis that each time ```operator<<``` is called I save stuff on the stack - inside of the object

Comment: @onqtam How does that make `ScopedMessage m = MessageBuilder() << x` not work?

Comment: @immibis because if I store stuff inside of ```MessageBuilder``` in a buffer and then assign the object to a ```ScopedMessage``` that buffer will have to move - which is what I'll implement right now after being told about that in the comments (last night I wasn't thinking straight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to create an object and call a method on it in one statement.

What is possible is to create a temporary object of type `X` and call a method on it, and then the result of that method can be assigned to a local object of type `Y` as long as `Y` has the appropriate constructor - like this:

```
Y lvalue = X() << arg1 << arg2;
```

But to solve my issue I did exactly what @Remy Lebeau suggested in the comments - now I'm doing it the same way as Catch, but I also "steal" the contents (the small buffer) of the temporary `InfoBuilder` when constructing the `InfoScope` object - with a copy constructor of `InfoBuilder`.

```
#define INFO(x) InfoScope ANONYMOUS(_CAPTURE_)(InfoBuilder() << x)
```

Not sure why I didn't think of this last night...